# Form not saving to database "through" intermediate tables

Tags: django

I have a custom form that is not saving to the database. I do not get any errors but the values do not save to the database. Any ideas?

views.py

```
def diseasestateoption(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateStateWithOptionsForm(request.POST, instance=state)

        if form.is_valid(): 
           for option_id in request.POST.getlist('options'):
               state_option = StateOption.objects.create(partstate=state, partoption_id=int(option_id))
               state_option.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

else:
    form = UpdateStateWithOptionsForm(instance=state)
```

models.py

```
class Option(models.Model):
        relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
        option = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class State(models.Model):
       state = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='state')
       relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")
       relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='StateOption')

class StateOption(models.Model):
       parttstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
       partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateStateWithOptionsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = State
       exclude = ['state', 'relevantdisease']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UpdateStateWithOptionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoption']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Comment: I don't think save_m2m is needed when using "through". I have to manually save the pointers to the intermediate table like I'm trying to do in the for loop. I'll try your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Problem is with getting option from POST, use-

```
request.POST.getlist('relevantoption')
```

in stead of

```
request.POST.getlist('options')
```

apart, why to use form here for single multiple choice field, even where you are modifying choices also and not using form.save too.